# Is there any reason behind bias towards max pooling over avg pooling?

Tags: deep-learning, max-pooling, pooling, average-pooling

Consider the following excerpt taken from the chapter named **[Using convolutions to generalize](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf#page=233)** from the textbook titled **Deep Learning with PyTorch** by *Eli Stevens et al*.

> Downsampling could in principle occur in different ways. Scaling an
> image by half is the equivalent of taking four neighboring pixels as
> input and producing one pixel as output. How we compute the value of
> the output based on the values of the input is up to us. We could
>
> - Average the four pixels. This average pooling was a common approach early on **but has fallen out of favor somewhat.**
> - Take the maximum of the four pixels. This approach, called max pooling, **is currently the most commonly used approach**, but it has
>   a downside of discarding the other three-quarters of the data.
> - Perform a strided convolution, where only every $N$-th pixel is calculated. A $3 \times 4$ convolution with stride 2 still incorporates input
>   from all pixels from the previous layer. The literature shows promise
>   for this approach, but it has not yet supplanted max pooling.

The paragraph is mentioning that the research community is biased towards max-pooling than average pooling. Is there any rational basis for such bias?

Answer (score 2):

I've found out rather a good explanation on [Quora](https://qr.ae/pGU8Y2).

[image]

**Max pooling** extracts the most salient features - edges, cusps, whatever.

**Average pooling** operates smoothly - collects features, that are relevant to any part of the image.

**Max pooling** throws some information, It can be thought as some sense of "forgetting", whereas **Average pooling** depends on the whole input, despite the output representation is compressed.

There are cases, where each of these operations may not be good for feature extracting (from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Toy-example-illustrating-the-drawbacks-of-max-pooling-and-average-pooling_fig2_300020038)):
[image]

In th first case **Max Pooling** will produce simply a white background, and in the second after **Average pooling** one will get a pale grey strip (although I think, it should be lighter, than depicted).

Probably It would make sense, to mix these two approaches, and pool half of the filters with **Max Pooling**, and another half with **Average Pooling**, although, I am not aware of the use of this approach in the literature.

The most flexible and expressive approach is the stridden convolution and the Average pooling, for example, is a particular case of it, but it introduces a certain (although not big) additional cost for storage of new parameters.